# MariaDB 10.1, select query gives table tmp table full (ERROR 1114)

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, centos7

I recently moved a script to start running a query from the same data on a different server/DB.  Both servers load the same data, but one is in the process of being decommissioned from real-time loading of current day's data.  The previous server was running mysql 5.1.73, this new one is running MariaDB 10.1.  The script is trying to run the following query with only the date changed (and I've obfuscated some columns and data filters, but kept col_X consistent in the query).

```
SELECT 
count(*) as num,
sec_to_time(floor(timestamp/1000000)) as true_time,
col_A,col_B,col_C,col_D,col_E,col_F,col_G,id,
sum(if(col_H = 3, 1, 0)) as num_A,
sum(if(col_H = 4,1,0)) as num_B 
FROM 
`some_table`  WHERE 
`some_table`.`date` = 20170622 AND 
(col_I not in ('VAL_A','VAL_B','VAL_C')) 
GROUP BY col_A, col_D, coL_E, col_F, col_B, col_C,
sec_to_time(floor(timestamp/1000000)) 
HAVING count(*) >= if(col_G='A',50,if(col_G='B',50,150)) 
ORDER BY sec_to_time(floor(timestamp/1000000));
```

On the new server, after the query runs for a while i'm getting this message:
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table '/home/mysql/tmp/#sql_61c5_0' is full

In that dir while the query is running i see 2 files that grow in size to around 1.2GB combined before this message happens.  I've gone through many variables, finding none different from the old server to new.  The first that seem to be mentioned are tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size, both of which are default 16MB on old and new server, but I've tried upping anyways.

The disk is not full, although they are smaller partitions:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md125      400G  247G  154G  62% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  373G  214G  160G  58% /mnt/nvme
```

(note /home/mysql is a symlink to /mnt/nvme/mysql, where mysql tables & tmp dir are located).

These are the only mysql variables set in /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
#Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 25G
innodb_log_file_size            = 768M
max_allowed_packet              = 104857600
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
max_heap_table_size = 134217728
tmp_table_size = 134217728
```

For the record the new server is running CentOS 7, but I can not find any OS limit that could be causing this either.  Any hints as to why this could be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Once the query terminates, it cleans up the tmp. So only during execution you might see the full disk.

Comment: Yes, and i've watched it carefully while it runs.  The 2 files created only reach ~1.1-1.2GB in size total before the operation terminates, with well over 100GB free on the disk.

Comment: 32-bit build?..

Comment: Shouldn't these be in the `GROUP BY`?  `col_G`, `id`

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Debugging:  Replace the HAVING and ORDER by simply LIMIT 1 -- to see if it is croaking on the first tmp table.  (There will be at least 2 tmp tables.)